# copy and paste code from safari (chrome) web inspector

Tags: google-chrome, safari, web-inspector

I want to copy some html code from the web inspector but am only able to copy one line at a  time. Is there any way to select a block of elements or all elements?

Comment: Does it work in any non-WebKit browsers you may have installed? Opera, Firefox, or Konqueror? What about RockMelt (a modded version of Chrome)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you right click on any element in the Web Inspector, then click "Copy as HTML" on the resulting pop-up menu, you can then paste the html for that element (and all enclosed elements) into your editor. You can get the entire document by doing this with the `<html>` element.

Comment: This does not appear to capture the inner content of IFRAME elements, despite the fact they show in the inspector hierarchy.

Comment: If you want to capture the inner content of an `iframe`, you'll have to select the first `html` tag within the `iframe` and proceed as @renozu suggested.

Answer (score 2):

On the console, try document.documentElement.outerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

You could view the html response from the Network section of Chrome

Comment: I can't see javascript generated html tags in the Network/Response tab.   Am I missing something here?

Comment: On the Console, try `document.html.outerHTML`.